# CardView with ImageView in RecyclerView doesn't fill screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-cardview

I am using a `CardView` with `ImageView` in `RecyclerView`.Below is xml code.

List Item(`CardView`) xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:elevation="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/feed_cradImage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/mysteps1"/>    
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Using it in a `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

But I am facing some issues:

1=>.I have set layout_width as "`match_parent`"  of `CardView` and `ImageView`. But, still `CardView` doesn't fill the full screen, and shows a margin in right side.

[image]

2=> If image size is small in width then `CardView` gets shrink as per image size. I want card not to shrink even if it is blank or have a samll image in it.

[image]

Note: I am using `Picasso` for fetching images from server.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY"  or android:scaleType="centerCrop" in ImageView

Answer (score 2):

add this to your ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the ImageView is filling the CardView correctly, but the image isn't filling correctly the ImageView. You could try to determine this by setting background colors to both elements and see what background is showing.

To solve the problem, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/feed_cradImage"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/mysteps1"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>    
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Image is filling the ImageView, but don't know why the result is same.

Comment: Did you tried my revision of yout xml? If so, the result is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce some elevation and check the result if it helps

```
app:elevation="4dp"
```